# How to say "slam a door open/shut" in Russian?

Tags: глаголы, phrase, лексикон

I would like to translate this sentence to Russian:

> The doors of the [beduin] tents slammed open and shut in the wind.

I found the verbs `хло́пнуть` and `захло́пнуть` for shutting or slamming a door. Though, to me, it seems like both terms mean closing a door rather than opening it.

However, **I would like to emphasize that the doors did both (open and close)**.

Right now I am using this sentence, which has a slightly different meaning:

> Двери палаток так хлопнули на ветру, что всё загремело.

Comment: Can you slam a door open? Doesn't it sound odd? I found some discussions on the topic and indeed people experiment with the word. I too can do an experiment and invent a new word: расхлопывать. Winnie-the-Pooh could easily use it.

Comment: I think a bedouin tent door or any other kind of tent opening would rather flap in the wind and not slam open or shut.

Comment: The door had a solid frame and would slam. But that's not the point here. Imagine a regular wooden door, if you don't like the idea of a tent having a door. :-)

Comment: Двери палаток, ударяясь, закрывались и открывались ветром.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Двери палаток хлопали, открываясь и закрываясь  от ветра.

Note that хлопнули is a single-event verb whereas хлопали is a multi-event verb which is probably what you wanted.

I think you used "open and shut" only to emphasize the repetitiveness of the slamming. In Russian you can safely drop "открываясь и закрываясь" because repetitiveness is already expressed by хлопали. Thus you can simply say :

> Двери палаток хлопали от ветра.

Or

> Ветер хлопал дверьми палаток.

Which sounds a bit more fiction-like, if that's what you are writing.

Comment: Sure, the slamming was a continuous process. Good point! But `хло́пать` only means (repetitively) slamming with a loud noise, it does not indicate any direction, right? In particular, it does not only mean `to slam shut`?

Comment: @user1438038 захлопнуть, meaning a single action, will mean *to slam shut*. Хлопать, a repeated action, will be understood as opening and closing a number of times.

Comment: still usually with respect to a door `хлопать` has connotations of `closure`, when we say or hear `он вышел, хлопнув дверью` we mean and understand that a person slam shut the door, not slam opened it on the way out

Answer (score 5):

Дверцы палаток то распахивались, то захлопывались от ветра (на ветру).

Comment: exactly........

Comment: **Fling open** is a word for **распахивать**, but people find it sounds not enough *slamming*.

Comment: I'd add _с шумом (распахивались)_, but I couldn't imagine any noise (like  хлопание) at _opening_ a tent door :)

Comment: I also agree, there should be two verbs +1

Answer (score 2):

You can go with a description. `Двери стучали на ветру.` (Or: `Дверь стучала на ветру` for singular.) This basically focuses on the doors producing the sound and not being shut or open, but it's obvious that doors produce a clapping sound by closing themselves.

---

Another issue is if your tents really have *doors* or the entry blocking device is called different. Compare `полы шатра`.

My `стучали` above implies hard doors, of wood or something. If it's fabric, I'd say `хлопали`, e.g. `Полотнища палаток хлопали на ветру`, `паруса хлопали от порывов ветра`.

Comment: Is was a metal frame covered with thick fabric. The material could not distort, so I would rather consider it a solid door. The door was not fluttering in the wind, like it would do on a regular camping tent.

Comment: I'd go for `стучали` in this case.

Comment: I have searched for both `Дверь хлопала на ветру` and `Дверь стучала на ветру` on Google. The first sentence gives me 800+ results, wheres I don't get a single result for the second one. I'm not a native speaker, so I can't tell, but `стучала` seems rather uncommon.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8C+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0%22+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83&oq=%22%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8C+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0%22+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83 ?

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend to employ the words "дверь" or "двери" in application to a beduin's tent. On this occasion, "полог" would be better. Then the verb describing the behaviour of this kind of cover is "трепетать":

"Полог его палатки трепетал на ветру"

You can say even stronger:

"Полог его палатки рвался и трепетал на ветру, так что внутри палатки всё сотрясалось."

Comment: In my case the tent had indeed a more or less solid door, so ``дверь`` suited well. But in general you are probably right, that the entrance to a beduin's tent is not commonly referred to as a "door". Thanks for the addition.

Comment: in that case, we маы say: "Дверь его шатра содрогалась и хлопала на ветру; да так что всё внутри сотрясалось"